# What's this message? It should be in italian

Tags: cipher

I received a challenge, deciphering "cgo feco a atm", the result, if a sentence, should be in Italian. I've tried the ceasar cipher without success, maybe you can help? Thanks!

Comment: "I received a challenge" Is this just a friendly challenge, or from an ongoing competition of sorts? If the latter, those are not allowed here until the competition is over.

Comment: It's the former.

Comment: Could it be an anagram?

Comment: I don't think many of us know italian, so like me they might not know when they've arrived at an answer lol